# Bash get two variables into one to recall that name as variable

Tags: bash, sh

What I want is that every start variable will be checked through the if statement. The only problem is that I don't know how to give get the "start1" and "start2" (etc.) through the if statement with `startx=start$i`

```
#!/bin/sh

start1="08:00:00"
start2="09:00:00"
start2="09:00:00"
i=1

while [ $i -lt 4 ]
    do
       startx=start$i
         if [[ "$timestamp" == "$startx" ]]
            echo "time is common with $startx"
         else
            ""
         fi & i=$[$i+1]
done
```

I've checked already with the declare function, somehow I don't get this to work?
Many thanks!

Comment: Please fix the syntax issues using this page [http://www.shellcheck.net/](http://www.shellcheck.net/) `Did you forget the 'then' for this 'if'?`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for indirect parameter expansion. Some other notes:

1. Use `#!/bin/bash`, not `#!/bin/sh`; this requires `bash`.
2. Don't use `$[...]`; it's an obsolete syntax. Use `$((...))`.

---

```
#!/bin/bash

start1="08:00:00"
start2="09:00:00"
start3="09:00:00"
i=1

while [ "$i" -lt 4 ]; do
  startx=start$i
  if [[ "$timestamp" == "${!startx}" ]]; then
    echo "time is common with ${!startx}"
  fi
  i=$(($i+1))
done
```

Answer (score -1):

You need to use [an array](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/arrays.html), instead of naming your variables that way.

Comment: There is no array in shells (other than bash)

Answer (score -1):

"Eval" is the magic trick of interpreted languages :

```
eval startx=\"\$start$i\"
```

Comment: `eval` can be dangerous and should not be used when unnecessary.

Comment: as $i is a number, there is no danger here.